# How to set dynamic parameter values to custom control from web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have one image button in the custom control like below.

```
     public string SearchTableName = string.Empty;
       public string SearchColumnName = string.Empty;
       public string SiteURL = string.Empty;
        ImageButton _imgbtn;
         protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
         {
           _imgbtn = new ImageButton();
           _imgbtn.ImageUrl = ImageURL;
           _imgbtn.OnClientClick = "ShowSearchBox('" + SiteURL +"/_layouts/CustomSearch/SearchPage/Searchpage.aspx?table_name=" + SearchTableName + " &column_name=" + SearchColumnName + "')";
         }
```

On Clicking of the image button I want to migrate to the another window which is a popup. For this I written a javascript function. I am setting the `SearchTableName` and `SearchColumnName` in the web page in which we are consuming this custom control like below. Before consuming I registered this control in web page with register tag.

`<ncc:SearchControl runat="server" ID="txtSearchControl"  />` In code behind file of this webpage I am using following code to set the values.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtSearchControl.ImageURL = "_layouts/Images/settingsicon.gif";
  txtSearchControl.SearchTableName = "Employees";
  txtSearchControl.SearchColumnName = "LastName";
  txtSearchControl.SiteURL = "http://Sp2010:8787";
 }
```

Now coming to the problem, when I click the image button the `SearchTableName` and `SearchColumnName` values are not coming. I think I am calling `OnClientClick` function, thats why the values are not being set. But how to set the values for the custom control  based on the values setting in the webpage. If I use the `Click` function will it serve my purpose? If so, how to call that javascript function from this click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got solution. I am initializing the values in the page `init` method in the custom control. Thats why the values i am setting in the visual webpart page are not being captured. Now I changed the initializing the values in `CreateChildControl` method. Now it works perfectly. Thank you.